# Why "The client certificate used for this request is not trusted by the Web server"?

Tags: python

I have created self signed certificate using IIS manager and pointed to default web site

And when I am trying to use it in requests.get method,  like below

```
r = requests.get("default web url", cert=config.CERT_FILE, allow_redirects=False, verify=True)
```

getting the error as Certificate Verify Failed.

```
Here cenfig.CERT_FILE = (cert_pub.crt, cert_priv.key)

cert.pub_crt is the selfsigned certificate and cert_priv.key is the private key for that self signed certificate
```

And if I use it with verify=False, then getting 403.16 error which is

```
The client certificate used for this request is not trusted by the Web server.
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue, I am getting this error from long time. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add yourself to the list of trusted CAs on IIS?

Comment: added the same self signed certificate to Trusted root certification authorities

Comment: You added the CA cert to the web server.  The client cert is generated from the CA cert.